# $a ^ x = |x + 2| - |2x + 8|$ has only one solution

Tags: logarithms, contest-math

So, this question was asked at a town-level olympiad.
$$a ^ x = |x + 2| - |2x + 8|$$
Knowing that there is only one solution, we must find a. So, basically $a ^ x$ is tangent to the some lines. I chose to get rid of the module to be it easier, but I am stuck at the first equation...
If we set $a < -4$, we get  $a ^ x = x + 6$, but I do not know how to continue. Any ideas? I suppose the other cases will be similar, right?

Comment: Graphing both sides of the equation will give you an intuition.

Comment: When graphed $a \approx 0.840896415$

Comment: Hint: Set $x = -4$ and solve for $x$.

Comment: Certainly, but during an olympiad, I do not think I could have done it.

Comment: The point is to plot the right hand side. The top contestants can be assumed to have seen plots of $a^x$ for various values of $a$. From staring at the plot you can the conclude that the only possible way to get a single solution does not come from tangency but from the sharp turn at $(-4,2)$. So $a^{-4}=2$

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I agree that's the observation to make. Any idea how we could have proven it without using calculus? (given that it's a "town-level olympiad", which I'm assuming doesn't require calculus). For example, if the graph was shifted much more to the left, then we could have a tangential value, so claiming that "it must go through the vertex" isn't necessarily valid.

Comment: A good question @CalvinLin! The line segment of possible tangency to the right of $(-4,2)$ has slope $-3$, and using the properties of derivatives it is easy to see that the plot of $a^x$ cannot match that at a position where $y<2$. I guess that it depends. May be the contest does not require rigorous justifications, just answers? That would change the set of required skills somewhat, but I would still call it a math contest :-). Not unlike the AHSME (or someacronym like that) which is multiple choice!

Comment: The question requires vigorous proofs.

Comment: @andueu Can you state which olympiad this is? Is calculus "allowed" in this olympiad? Is it Tournament of the Towns?

Comment: It is a contest to get to the county olympiad from Suceava, 1987. Theoretically, calculus is allowed, but the question was given to 10-graders, who have not studied calculus yet.

Answer (score 3):

$$a ^ x = |x + 2| - |2x + 8|$$
Maximum value for the right side occurs when $|2x+8|$ equals $0$ $\Rightarrow x=-4$.

Making sure the left side $a^x$ passes through $(-4, 2)$ will do.